# Sentence writing - use of pronouns

Tags: sentence

Which of the following is a correct sentence?

> - The teacher is able to choose a relevant classroom experience but is unable to reflect on it.
> - The teacher is able to choose a relevant classroom experience but he /she  is unable to reflect on it.

Answer (score 1):

They are both perfectly acceptable.